# PHP SQL Keep adding row['value'] with previous inside loop

Tags: php, sql

here is my code-

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM payment WHERE customerid='$id'";
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    {
    echo $row['fraction_payment'];
    }    
}
```

What im trying to do: constantly keep adding `$row['fraction_payment']` with the previous value.

if database value of

```
fraction_payment 1 = 100 
fraction_payment 2 = 200 
fraction_payment 3 = 300
```

expected result will be:

```
$row['fraction_payment'][1] = 100
$row['fraction_payment'][2] = 300
$row['fraction_payment'][3] = 600
```

How should i proceed to do that in PHP?

Comment: OT: Don't forget to change to mysqli prepared statements to prevent sql injection!

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, pretty self explanatory:

```
$total = 0;
$sql="SELECT * FROM payment WHERE customerid='$id'";
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  {
    $total += $row['fraction_payment'];
    echo $total;
  }    
}
```

Comment: I think he was wanting to re-assign that back into row over the previous values (judging by his example of expected result) ?

Answer (score 1):

```php
$sql="SELECT * FROM payment WHERE customerid='$id'";
if ($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
  $sum = 0;
  $result = [];
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  {
    $sum += $row['fraction_payment'];
    $result[] = $sum;
  }
  var_dump($result);
}
```

And don't forget about SQL injections: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the example. :)